# BouncyCastle error: can't recognise key type in ECDSA based signer

Tags: java, rsa, bouncycastle, elliptic-curve

I have been doing some simple testing with BouncyCastle's crypto library and RSA's crypto library. What I am doing is generating a private/public key pair like so:

```
KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC", "JsafeJCE");
kpg.initialize(new ECGenParameterSpec("secp384r1"));
KeyPair kp = kpg.genKeyPair();
PrivateKey priv = kp.getPrivate();
PublicKey pub = kp.getPublic();
```

Then I generate the signature like so

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA384/ECDSA","BC");
```

and I try to sign the private key:

```
sig.initSign(priv);
```

All of this gets me the error:

java.security.InvalidKeyException: can't recognise key type in ECDSA based signer

When I BC and JsafeJCE, I get no error and everything is fine. Works also if both providers are BC. So why is it I can't sign the JsafeJCE generated key with the BC lib?

Answer (score 4):

Bouncycastle requires that the private key used for its signing implementation must be one of its own. I don't know why you'd choose different providers for the various pieces in any event.

Comment: What happens when the provider at the other end is different?  So I am working with an existing application that uses the JsafeJCE provider. I am using BC on my end. Will BC be able to verify everything correctly?

Comment: Yes, the data is transported using provider-independent, standard formats.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same issue by following the below steps:

1) Create static provider:

```
private static BouncyCastleProvider bouncyCastleProvider;
public static final BouncyCastleProvider BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER = new BouncyCastleProvider();
static {
    bouncyCastleProvider = BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER;
}
```

2) Generate keyPair:

```
KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA", bouncyCastleProvider);
g.initialize(ecSpec, random);
KeyPair keyPair = g.generateKeyPair();
```

3) If you want to sign something using key:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withECDSA", bouncyCastleProvider);
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(signedData);
signature.sign();
```

It worked for me, and will hopefully work for you as well.